# Code not setting RichTextBox to a StringCollection item value

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

And I would like to share this issue with you.

This piece of code:

```
Dim np As New notepad
np.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Settings.SDBodies.ToString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
```

Is doing nothing. It is supposed to do what it is supposed to do. It is susposed to set the RichTextBox text to the StringCollection Item Value.

Yes, **notepad** and **RichTextBox1** is defined.

1. **RichTextBox1** is the RichTextBox I am talking about.
2. And **notepad** is the form **RichTextBox1** is in.

Please help!

Comment: It may be supposed to do what it's supposed to do but it is doing what it's doing.  If your intention is to get an item from the collection by index then that's what you should do, but it's not what you're doing now.  Get rid of the `ToString` call in there.  That is converting the `StringCollection` to a single `String`, which is certainly not what you should be doing or what you want to do.

Comment: Apart from that, you are creating a NEW form and setting the `Text` of a `RichTextBox` on that.  In the code you've shown us, you're not actually displaying that form.  Unless you're displaying the form elsewhere, you can't see that form so you can't see the `RichTextBox` so you can't see the text.

Answer (score 0):

New code:

```
If My.Settings.SDBodies Is Nothing Then
                    My.Settings.SDBodies = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
                End If

                Dim np As New notepad
                ListBox1.Enabled = False
                For i = 0 To My.Settings.SDBodies.Count - 1
                    If i = ListBox1.SelectedIndex Then
                        np.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Settings.SavedDocuments(i)
                        ListBox1.Enabled = True
                    Else
                        ' Do nothing
                    End If
                Next
```